# Office 365 - Forward email to external domain without a mailbox

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, mail-forwarding, office365

We have office 365.

We want to forward email addresses from our domain to people outside our domain.

i.e.

support@mydomain.com -> support@externalcompany.com

One way I think I can do this is:

- Create a Mail Contact with the external address
- Create a distribution list that has the internal address with the mail contact above

Are there any other better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "quick" way to forward a adress is to create a external contact with a internal email address and a forward email address ("External Email Address")

**1. Create External contact with External email address.**

```
New-MailContact -Name "Display Name" -ExternalEmailAddress "External Email Address"
```

Like this:

```
New-MailContact -Name "Bjoster Admin" -ExternalEmailAddress "bjoster@external.example.com"
```

**2. Set External contact email address to internal email address and forwarding email address**

```
New-MailContact "Bjoster Admin" -EmailAddresses "SMTP:<Office 365 User Email Address>,<External Recipient Email Address>"
```

Like this one:

```
Set-MailContact "David Wilkins" -EmailAddresses "SMTP:bjoster@example.com,bjoster@external.example.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

To narrow down the issue, I'd like to confirm with you which of the following is the case:

1. Automatically forward from an internal mailbox to an external mailbox?
2. Automatically forward from multiple internal mailboxes to one external mailbox?
3. Automatically forward from one internal mailbox to multiple external mailboxes?
   In addition, you can configure mail forwarding by referring to this link: [Configure email forwarding - Microsoft 365 admin | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/configure-email-forwarding?view=o365-worldwide#configure-email-forwarding)

Comment: We're not very fond of link only-answers. Can you add the actual answer to your answer, so it's more useful in the future?